# Xcode + Snow Leopard in IOS 7

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios7, osx-snow-leopard

I have an iMac that came to me at least 5 years. He had a great performance, however since I put the Mavericks he is absurdly slow, so I decided to go back to Snow Leopard.

I made an overview of the programs that I use and 90% of them are compatible with Snow Leopard, Xcode excerpt. As I have not I schedule for IOS ('m willing to learn), I would like to know the following:

I want to use Phonegap (Cordova) to develop for Android and IOS. Programs compiled with Xcode 3 (4 e 5 versions only run from LION) run 6 e 7 in IOS?

Thank you!

Comment: older versions of Xcode might run on leopard but i doubt Xcode 5 would run. you better check with apple web site support section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode 3 is quite old, it can run on 10.4 (Tiger, pre-Intel) I believe. Snow Leopard can run up to XCode 4.3 (or there about), and Lion can go up to 4.6.

From what little I know about Phonegap, it's not as good as it sounds (IMHO), there's a price to pay for writing in Javascript and bypassing all the rest.

My 2 cents, research this topic well before diving in.